# XPath XML data parsing in android very slow

Tags: java, android, xml, xpath

The xpath.evaluate parsing in android takes about 8-9 seconds for each. I use about 8 different xpath evaluate methods and my program takes about 1 min 35 seconds to load.

I'm using an AsyncTask for this purpose and I don't want to implement other parsers which are not included in the standard JDK.

One of the many laggy xpath evaluate code blocks :

```
for (int i=1;i<=36;i++){
                      InputSource source16 = new InputSource(new StringReader(hourly));

                      try{
                       humidity = xpath.evaluate("/response/hourly_forecast/forecast["+i+"]/humidity", source16);


                      }
                      catch (Exception e) {
                      e.printStackTrace();
                                  }
                      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same trouble when I was doing a swing program with Java SE. I had to call xpath.evalute method about 12 different times, each time taking atleast 2-3 seconds which made my program awfully slow.

The simple solution was to use a substring. It might sound naive and a lot of work, but it actually works if you just have under 10 different parameters to parse from the XML and most importantly the XML is reliable and well formatted.

In your case with just 8 different parameters to parse in the entire document, this method is quite easily achievable. Just use a for-loop too.

Implement something like this :
First, parse your entire XML document to a string. Let's call it yourXmlDoc. And store the values of humidity in a String array.

```
num1=0;
num2=0;
num3=0;
for (int i=0;i<*number of times you need to repeat*;i++){
num1=yourXmlDoc.indexOf("humidity",num3);
num2=yourXmlDoc.indexOf("/humidity",num1);
num3=num2;
humidity[i]=yourXmlDoc.substring(num1+9,num2-1);
System.out.println(humidity[i]);

.. continue with more parameters to parse and let its starting point be num3
}
```

P.S. This is possible only in case of a well formatted XML. Otherwise its very hard to implement and is a waste of time.

Comment: Well, it took me roughly twice the amount of code and half an hour to implement this. My XML was well formatted of course. Good thing is, it reduced my program's lag by 97% to be exact. It runs in 3 seconds now :) Thank you for this solution. I started out looking for a good parser, but I dont think it can get any faster than this.Out of the total 3 seconds, this process might be taking less than 1 second. I'm voting this as the right answer :)

Answer (score 0):

try to get this line to top of your for loop, i'm pretty sure it will solve your problem. But if it doesn't try to not to use it. I mean try to read your string into an inputstream and work with it.

```
InputSource source16 = new InputSource(new StringReader(hourly));
for (int i=1;i<=36;i++){
                  try{
                   humidity = xpath.evaluate("/response/hourly_forecast/forecast["+i+"]/humidity", source16);


                  }
                  catch (Exception e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
                              }
                  }
```

As we know string proccess can be a torture if you don't be more careful.

Comment: If I move that "InputSource" line to the top, then it evaluates only 1 time and then gives an Exception --> java.io.IOException: Stream closed

Comment: Because inputSource reads and finishes. Please use a String variable or something else then to evaluate

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4197507/whats-a-simple-way-in-java-to-evaluate-an-xpath-on-a-string-and-return-a-result

Comment: I tried everything including changing the input source to String, Input stream, byte array input stream. Even tried initializing the input source itself to string and  byte array input stream but to no avail. The program does not work.

Comment: It does not work. Errors include evrything from Premature end of file fatal error to "javax.xml.transform.TransformerException"