# Default namespaces in soapUI XPath assertions

Tags: xpath, soapui

I'm trying to create an XPath Match assertion in soapUI against the following XML to see if an element exists:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ns2:executeResponse xmlns:ns2="http://ws.namf09.anzlic.org.au">
         <responses id="?" xmlns="http://namf09.anzlic.org.au">
            <result status="OK" completed="true" hasErrorsInResponseElements="false"/>
            <response id="200.1">
               <responseResult>
                  <address>
                     <streetNumber1>2</streetNumber1>
                     <streetName>sydney</streetName>
                     <streetType>SQ</streetType>
                     <localityName>sydney</localityName>
                     <stateTerritory>NSW</stateTerritory>
                     <postcode>2000</postcode>
                  </address>
               </responseResult>
            </response>
         </responses>
      </ns2:executeResponse>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

My first attempt was `boolean(//address)`, which soapUI said was false. But, when I've let soapUI work out the namspaces for me, it has come up with:

```
declare namespace ns2='http://ws.namf09.anzlic.org.au';
declare namespace ns1='http://namf09.anzlic.org.au';
declare namespace soapenv='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/';
boolean(//ns1:address)
```

This works, but I don't understand where the `ns1` namespace has come from. I assume it's a default, but how could I work this out without soapUI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The namespace prefix in the XML document does not have to be the same as the namespace prefix in your assertion. It's the *URI* that has to match. In the case of default namespaces, the URI still has to match, so you have to call it *something* in XPath/XQuery.

In your XML document, the `<address>` element is in the `http://namf09.anzlic.org.au` namespace, which refers to the National Address Management Framework.

In order to give that URI a moniker that makes sense, instead of purely random one like `ns1`, let's call it `namf`:

```
declare namespace namf='http://namf09.anzlic.org.au';
boolean(//namf:address)
```

Answer (score 0):

**nsX** are the default namespaces that SoapUI generates from the response.

To evaluate xPath expressions you need an editor able to run xPath functions. 
Try this online parser:

> https://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html#ad-output

These functions (APIs) are also available for program languages like Java:

> [What's a simple way in java to evaluate an xpath on a string and return a result string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4197507/whats-a-simple-way-in-java-to-evaluate-an-xpath-on-a-string-and-return-a-result)