# Query Match in SoapUI doesn't work for a proper Xpath

Tags: xpath, soapui

So i got this XML:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
   <s:Header>
      <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">http://http://someurl.de/test/schema/function</a:Action>
      <a:MessageID>urn:uuid:4f318e88-c586-42c4-a2e8-2d9fdd18daca</a:MessageID>
      <a:ReplyTo>
         <a:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</a:Address>
      </a:ReplyTo>
      <a:To s:mustUnderstand="1">http://localhost:8088/mockMessageServiceViaWsHttpX509TokenWithoutSct</a:To>
   </s:Header>
   <s:Body>
      <ReceiveMessages xmlns="http://someurl.de/test/schema">
         <request xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <ServiceNameIdentifier>single</ServiceNameIdentifier>
            <ServiceNameQualifier/>
         </request>
      </ReceiveMessages>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

I used several XPath expressions so far like this one:

`count(//ServiceNameIdentifier[.='single'])`

or this

`count(//ReceiveMessages/request/ServiceNameIdentifier[.='single'])`

and i'm checking if that result is 1.

I checked this:

`//ReceiveMessages/request/ServiceNameIdentifier/text()`

and tested if the result is "single" but also to no avail....

At the site https://www.freeformatter.com/ it worked. In SoapUI it doesn't and i have no idea what i'm doing wrong...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Default namespaces in soapUI XPath assertions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49849723/default-namespaces-in-soapui-xpath-assertions)

Comment: Not really. I got 3 different endpoints set up with each 2 or 3 responses. For the first 2 it works but not with the third one and i have no clue why...

Comment: That was an auto message from duplication flag. Do note that `ReceiveMessages`, `request` and `ServiceNameIdentifier` elements are under `http://someurl.de/test/schema` namespace URI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Namespaces always hurt my head, so I try to bypass them whenever possible. The following XPath uses `local-name()` to ignore the namespace of the elements, and the `contains` function to test for the contents:

```
count(//*[local-name() = 'ServiceNameIdentifier'][contains(.,'single')])
```

For your payload, this returns 1:

[image]

Comment: You, Sir, are the blast!! This works perfectly! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You need to define and use namespaces, as shown here https://www.soapui.org/docs/functional-testing/point-and-click-testing/point-and-click-with-xpath.html

Comment: I did like this 

```declare namespace s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"

declare namespace a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"

count(//s:Envelope/s:Body/ReceiveMessage/request/ServiceNameIdentifier[.='single']) > 0
```
But it's not working...

Comment: @Kazoooka you are missing a namespace for "http://someurl.de/test/schema" (if you press "Declare" soapui will generate them for you). Then you will have something like `//s:Envelope/s:Body/d:ReceiveMessage/i:request/i:ServiceNameIdentifier[.='single']`

Comment: I did this now: 
```

    declare namespace s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
    declare namespace a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"
    declare namespace i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    declare namespace ns="http://someurl.de/test/schema"
    count(//s:Envelope/s:Body/ns:ReceiveMessage/i:request/i:ServiceNameIdentifier[.='single']) > 0
```


but it sadly still doesn't work...

Also i don't find a "Declare" Button.