# How to get XML namespace value via Xpath

Tags: xml, xpath, soapui

How can i get the "273" value of ns1:bookId, when I have an xml response like this:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soap:Body xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
      <ns2:createResponse ns1:bookId="273" xmlns:ns1="http://www.example.com/">
   </soap:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

SoapUI doesn't accept this pattern: `//ns2:createResponse/@ns1:bookId`

Comment: Don't bother with it, I just copied a random part of an xml. The question is how do you define an Xpath for that namespace?

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49851246/3710053

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ignore namespaces in XPath:

```
//*[local-name()="createResponse"]/@*[local-name()="bookId"]
```

Comment: I think you probably intended to call `local-name()` rather than `name()`.