# how can (Java) XPath return a number?

Tags: java, xml, xpath

My XPath is just `/html/body/count(hr)`. I want to count the number of XHTML horizontal rules. This is for a test assertion, so if the number changes I want the assertion diagnostic text to reflect the number.

But `xpath.compile(xpathExpression)` throws "javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: Unknown nodetype: count"

El Goog says that an XPath expression can return a number; so can (Java's) XPath mechanics access it?

---

also this must fit inside an Android tablet's tests, so I can't use any third party XML parser that would destabilize my build. Saxon could do it

Comment: What about `count(/html/body/hr)`  ?

Comment: thanks; that worked and I'm getting a `XPathConstants.NUMBER` now. I will leave my question up because I think `/html/body/count(hr)` should have been the equivalent

Comment: Pleased to be able to help. I expanded my comment into a full answer. Please accept :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a count of the tags at that path. The path is `/html/body/hr`.

`count()` is a function, not a tag or part of a path. So `count()` cannot come after `/html/body/` because then it's looking for a `count` tag, and probably doesn't know what the `()` is.

So try:

```
count(/html/body/hr)
```

Comment: I figured out how to express what I'm stuck on. I think that `/html/body/count(hr)` should return a list of all counts relative to each <body> tag, such as for if there weren't only just one. No biggie; the code works now tx all

Comment: @Phlip, your syntax `/html/body/count(hr)` is indeed possible, but only in XPath 2 and later, not in XPath 1.0. To use XPath 2 or later in Java you need Saxon 9 or 10 or 11 or any of the XQuery engines/implementations in Java, like BaseX or eXist-db.

Comment: @MartinHonnen  Sounds like that could be a legit first class answer, and an even better one than mine  :)

Comment: @Stewart, in the general context of Java and XPath I agree, but as the poster said he wants to work with built-in libraries on Android I guess that means he wouldn't want to try to introduce a dependency on Saxon.

Comment: thanks all. For those of you who test (pristine) XHTML inside Android, or otherwise without Saxon etc, here's my assertions that spot-check details in your web page without getting stuck on the intermediate tags: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61831914/193980